# How to alter undirected, binary graph to have specific graph-analytical characteristics while keeping others constant

Tags: clustering, graph-theory, networks, integral, igraph

I am working on a undirected, binary graph (derived from functional neuroimaging). I would like to alter this graph to change specific graph-characteristics (e.g. a specific value for the global clustering coefficient or the average minimal path length) while keeping all other graph-characteristics constant (or as many other as possible). 
There are some references how to alter a graph to have a specific clustering coefficient (e.g. [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/26148/create-a-random-graph-based-on-the-degree-distribution-and-clustering-coefficien) suggests [Wang](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.6802) or the  [block two-level Erdos-Renyi model](http://www.sandia.gov/~tgkolda/feastpack/)). There are existing implementations for the clustering coefficient ([here](http://sbansal.com/ClustRNet/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/alimuldal/c7e2905f455cac3f01ed)). Are there similar references with respect to average minimal path length?

Answer (score 1):

You could the use the principle of the [Watts-Strogatz model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watts_and_Strogatz_model) ([Watts'98](http://www.stevenstrogatz.com/articles/collective-dynamics-of-small-world-networks-pdf)): in the article, they show empirically that randomly rewiring a very few links in a lattice allows largely decreasing the average distance while keeping a relatively high clustering coefficient.

In this model, a parameter `p` allows controlling the (expected) proportion of rewired links. For each rewired link, one randomly selects one of its end-points, then exchange it for a different (randomly drawn) node. You can find an implementation in igraph, see file `igraph/src/games.c#igraph_watts_strogatz_game` on [their GitHub](https://github.com/igraph/igraph).

You could implement this simple mechanism, apply it to your own data, and study how playing with `p` affects the other topological proporties of interest. But intuitively, it seems hard to completely control one topological property without changing the others. For instance, in a previous work I studied how a different rewiring process (designed to produce a community structure) affects the average distance, degree correlation and average distance of a network, and the effects were very different, and sometimes very strong.